# JavaScript for loop not a function error on getElementsByClassName iteration

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

I have a equal height function. I have 3 containers. Inside the containers are tiles that I like to set equal height. I want to set different offset heights for each container tiles; so I iterate containers. I have following setup:

```js
var setTileHeight = function() {
  var containers = document.getElementsByClassName('a-r');

  for (var i in containers) {
    var tiles = containers[i].getElementsByClassName('span-3');
    console.log(tiles);
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  setTileHeight();
};
```

```css
.span-3 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.span-12 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.text {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="msection2-g span-12">
  <div class="a-r span-12">
    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="msection2-g">
  <div class="a-r">
    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="msection2-g">
  <div class="a-r">
    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I run this code I get following message in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: containers[i].getElementsByClassName is not a function

I guess this error comes after all elements iterated and/or when there is another element present in the `container` object such as length. Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: try changing     var tiles = containers[i].getElementsByClassName('span-3');
to     var tiles = i.getElementsByClassName('span-3');

Comment: @Satya Still no result.

Comment: @JanakaDombawela just created a fiddle and its working fine fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7af73f1w/

Comment: Use `for` and not `for..in`. `for..in` is suited to loop on objects. In older browsers it will also loop on `length` and any other properties(*element ids in this case*).

Comment: @Rajesh seems like it was the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @JanakaDombawela Great. Just a pointer though, next time please create a **minimal and verifiable** example. Your html itself is 500+ lines. Don't do that. SO has character limit for answer (30000) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, error is due to improper looping structure. `for..in` loops over properties of an object and not on elements of array.

**Sample**

```js
var setTileHeight = function() {
  var containers = document.getElementsByClassName('a-r');

  for (var i in containers) {
    try{
    var tiles = containers[i].getElementsByClassName('span-3');
    console.log(tiles);
    }catch(e){
      console.log("Error due to incorrect value of i: ", i)
    }
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  setTileHeight();
};
```

```css
.span-3 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.span-12 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.text {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="msection2-g span-12">
  <div class="a-r span-12">
    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="msection2-g">
  <div class="a-r">
    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="msection2-g">
  <div class="a-r">
    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span-3">
      <div class="span-12">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                            Text - <span>37 items</span>
                                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can refer to `for` version using this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/9x3p4wnz/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is because `for..in` is taking the keys from the `containers: HTMLCollection` if you're wanting to loop through the nodes please try a `for` loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
  var tiles = containers[i].getElementsByClassName('span-3');
}
```

Comment: Just a pointer, please check all answers before posting as I already addressed the same. :-)

Comment: I felt, an example and little deeper explanation would help other people who land on this. When I was learning examples helped me understand concepts much easier

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over all child having class `span-3` under div `a-r`.And you should check length of element rather than adding try catch in code.

```
<script>    
   var setTileHeight = function () {

   var containers = document.getElementsByClassName('a-r');
            for (var i in containers) {
                var allchildren = containers[i].children;
                for (var j in allchildren) {
                    var cls = allchildren[j].className;
                    if (cls === 'span-3') {
                    var item = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);                    
                    if (item && item.length > 0)
                        item[0].setAttribute("style", "height:100px");
                    }                 
                }    
            }
   };

   window.onload = function () {
            setTileHeight();
   };
</script>
```